# problemas con mostrar y reproducir video en un proyecto con django-python html5

Tags: python, html5, django

Estoy haciendo una página web con django-python y quiero mostrar un vídeo que tengo en la carpeta local. He intentado utilizar los Tag de HTML5 como `<video>` pero no me funciona y he intentado también realizarlo con VLC pero tampoco me reproduce el vídeo en el proyecto. Si lo pongo en un fichero aparte el código y lo abro en el navegador si funciona, pero en el proyecto no...

Comment: jma, te recomiendo que sigas el [tour]. ¿Es posible nos muestres un ejemplo mínimo de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando Django entonces tendrás que hacerlo a través de un fichero estático mediante la clausula `static`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="{% static 'carpeta/video.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: El codigo que he probado es el siguiente:

`
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{ STATIC_URL }}videos/360p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
`
En el settings.py tengo configurado:
`STATIC_URL = '/static/' `

y dentro de la carpeta static tengo otra de videos en la que se encuentra el video que quiero reproducir... he probado de otras muchas maneras que he visto pero no consigo reproducir el video

Gracias!!